# How to use TikaDotNet from IronPython after installing with Nuget

Tags: nuget, ironpython

I'd like to use TikaDotNet from IronPython.  I've installed it using Nuget.  Using the CMD command `nuget list TikaDotNet` Im told TikaDotNet 1.14.1 and TikaDotNet.TextExtractor 1.14.1 are both installed.  I am not quite sure how to load this into my IronPython windows app.

Is there a correct way to do this?
All these fail for me....

```
clr.AddReference("TikaOnDotNet.TextExtractor")

clr.AddReference("TikaOnDotNet")

import TikaDotNet

import TikaDotNet.TextExtractor

from TikaDotNet import TextExtractor
```

FYI - I am using Geany, not Visual Studio.

Comment: Fail how? Have you tried adding the location where the TikaDotNet DLLs reside to the search path in ironpython?

Comment: No I have not.  I can try that from home, however at work I don't have privileges to modify site.py.  They are failing meaning "module not found" or "not recognized".